# Is it possible to disable the Alt-Space key combination in a Java application

Tags: java, windows, swing, menu, systemmenu

The Alt-space key combination in Windows brings up the "Window Menu" -i.e., the menu you get when right-clicking the title bar.  It has items "Restore", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Close", etc.  I'd like to disable it.  Is there any way to do so in a Java Swing program?  I believe the OS gets this before it gets to the application.

Comment: The short answer, AFAIK is no...

Comment: *"I'd like to disable it."*  ***Why?***  Any app. that broke such basic functionality would immediately get uninstalled from *my* PC.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Why, you ask?  Because the users of this system work with no other program than this one and use the keyboard almost exclusively.  Their Windows is stripped down of everything, no Outlook, no Office, no browsers.  This system replaces an ancient legacy system.  If their fingers slip, they might type Alt-Space accidentally, and all subsequent typing goes into the menu.  It would be nice to be able to prevent this, although it looks to be virtually impossible.  In any normal situation, I'd agree with you that it makes no sense to do this.

Comment: @SteveCohen did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @DirkBoer It's been seven years and I've retired since.  I don't think I ever did.

Comment: @DirkBoer I actually don't browse SO anymore but I do still get emails informing me when one of my posts has been answered or commented on.  Then I like to look.